# How a Line can Detect From canvas and Remove in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have many lines in `Canvas`. I just want to **detect** that which line is **clicked** and want to **Remove** it from children of `Canvas` in WPF?? any Solution
thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add a MouseLeftButtonDown event for your canvas and a KeyDown event for your WPF.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCanvas.MouseLeftButtonDown += MyCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        this.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
    }
```

When your left mouse clicks on one of the lines, it should highlight the selection. When it clicks on something else, it should un-highlight the previous selection.

```
    private Line _selectedLine;
    private void MyCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        object testPanelOrUi = InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(this)) as FrameworkElement;

        // if the selection equals _selectedLine, i.e. the line has been selected already
        if (Equals(testPanelOrUi, _selectedLine)) return;

        // The selection is different.
        // if _selectedLine is not null, revert color change.
        if (_selectedLine != null)
        {
            UnHighlightSelection();
        }

        // if testPanelOrUi is not a line.
        if (!(testPanelOrUi is Line)) return;

        // The selection is different and is a line.
        _selectedLine = (Line) testPanelOrUi;
        HighlightSelection(_selectedLine);
    }
```

Your `HighlightSelection()` and `UnHighlightSelection()` can be similar to the followings:

```
    private void HighlightSelection(Line selectedob)
    {
        selectedob.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
    }

    private void UnHighlightSelection()
    {
        //if nothing has been selected yet.
        if (_selectedLine == null) return;

        _selectedLine.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        _selectedLine = null;
    }
```

Then you can define your `Delete` and `KeyDown` actions. When Delete key is pressed, the selection should be deleted.

```
    private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            DeleteLine();
        }
    }

    public void DeleteLine()
    {
        //if nothing has been selected yet.
        if (_selectedLine == null) return;

        //if the selection has been deleted.
        if (!MyCanvas.Children.Contains(_selectedLine)) return;

        UnHighlightSelection();
        MyCanvas.Children.Remove(_selectedLine);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks Its Works :) :) and helped alot @Anthony